# Find XPath of --httpPort

Tags: xml, ansible

Im trying to change the port in my Jenkins xml file. Having issues identifying the correct xpath.

```
<service>
  <id>Jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins automation server.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>

  <executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>
  <onfailure action="restart" />
  <extensions>
    <extension enabled="true" 
               className="winsw.Plugins.RunawayProcessKiller.RunawayProcessKillerExtension"
               id="killOnStartup">
      <pidfile>%BASE%\jenkins.pid</pidfile>
      <stopTimeout>10000</stopTimeout>
      <stopParentFirst>false</stopParentFirst>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</service>
```

And here is my Ansible Playbook. Im pretty certain I haven't figured out the correct xpath yet.

```
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Set port to 8888
    xml:             
      path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml
      xpath: /service/arguments/httpPort
      value: 8888
```

Any idea how to get the xpath of --httpPort?

Comment: Why to not set the port when starting the jenkins (java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8888) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how to get the xpath of --httpPort?

You have an incorrect mental model of what xpath does. The "X" is for XML, which stops at `<argument>`; XML does not do parsing of character data inside its tags

That said, the thing you'll want is to *fetch* the value of `<argument>`, mutate it, *then* write it back using what you were trying to do to begin with:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - xml:
      path: jenkins.xml
      xpath: /service/argument
      content: text
    register: arg
  - xml:
      path: jenkins.xml
      xpath: /service/argument
      value: '{{ arg.matches[0].argument | regex_replace("--httpPort=8080", "--httpPort=1234") }}'
```